# Colorir Linha do Listview Delphi Android

Tags: android, delphi

Como mudar a cor de uma linha do listview Delphi / Android ?

Para que tenha a cor alterada conforme alguma condição seja verdadeira:

```
se a = 1 then 
   listview.linha?.? := clBlue
entao 
   listview.linha?.? := clRed;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione um componente `TListView`.

Em nosso exemplo vamos popular o ListView no evento `FormCreate`:

```
var
  i, j : Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    with Listview1.Items.Add do begin
      Caption := 'Item '+ IntToStr(i);
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        Subitems.Add('SubItem '+IntToStr(i)+IntToStr(j));
    end;
```

No evento `OnCustomDrawItem` do componente `TListView`:

```
  if Odd(item.index) then
    Listview1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clred//Todas as linhas Ímpares
  else
    ListView1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;//Todas as linhas pares
```

Agora basta usar a imaginação e começar a adicionar as Condições!

Comment: mas o Problema que no android não tem "OnCustomDrawItem" é exatamente ai que o negocio tá pegando... as opções do canvas.brush não é mais a mesma.

Comment: Estou imcapacitado de compilar uma versão android, mas.... Tem um evento chamado OnPaint que aceita o Canvas, eu ja usei algo semelhante como: ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.Text.TextColor := $F6F6F6;